# How do I go back to Windows 7 from Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

I had Windows 7 Starter on my EeePC and then made a BackupImage on my portable USB drive and then got Ubuntu. I like Ubuntu, but it takes much of my battery and I must go back to Windows 7 Starter for software reasons.

How do I do that?

When I go to the bootmenu with <kbd>F2</kbd> I can choose the USBdrive as booting device, but nothing happens.

Comment: What type of file is on your USB Drive? How did you back it up?

Comment: I created a WindowsImageBackup and the files of this backup are named as followd on my USBdrive Backup2012-03-20 070814 with in it several files like this one _389f5836-c3be-40a6-82f1-a6c49d1fe0b6_Writer542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f_.

Comment: The WindowsImageBackup also contains the files Catalog, SPPMetadataCache and a MediaID file.

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/114818)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a System Image Recovery.  To do so please follow the guide [Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/675-system-image-recovery.html)